# Urlrewriting in Jboss 4.0.3

Tags: web-applications, jboss, url-rewriting, rule

I deployed a web application using JBoss4.0.3 application server. In this web application i am using urlrewritefilter-4.0.3 for url rewriting and i wrote a rule in urlrewrite.xml as

```
<rule>
    <from>subCategories/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$*</from>
    <to>browseCategories.do?category=$1&amp;subjectName=$2</to>
</rule>
```

I want to convert url from `https://localhost:8080/subCategories/sub11758/Physics` to
`https://localhost:8080/browseCategories.do?category=sub11758&subjectName=Physics`

but urlrewriter is not redirecting to desired url. Please help me to correct this or suggest a way to debug urlrewriting.